# Wordpress - Check if the title is used in nav menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just added a filter to `the_title` using the following code:

```
    function my_filter($content) {
           $content .= '<div class="meta">';
           $content .= 'My filter';
           $content .= '</div>';

       return $content;
   }

     if(!is_single()){
             add_filter('the_title', 'my_filter', 1);
     }
```

What I noticed is the filter is also added in those titles which are used in the `wp_nav_menu()` .
I only want to display the filter after the title if the current page is not a single post page.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to remove the filter as well:

```
if(!is_single()){
  add_filter('the_title', 'my_filter', 1);
}
else {
  remove_filter('the_title', 'my_filter', 1);
}
```

My guess is that once the filter is added on a non-single page, it stays applied until removed.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Comment: Interesting. What happens when you check if the filter is present on various pages? aka, `if(has_filter('the_title', 'my_filter')) { echo 'Has filter'; }` That might help you debug.